# XLwings, copying values from one workbook to another workbook?

Tags: excel, python-2.7, xlwings

I need to iterate through a bunch of excel workbooks and grab a value from each one and paste that value to a new workbook, so basically consolidating results from a bunch of excel workbooks to a single workbook . The way my script runs now it copies and pastes the value back to the original workbook. What do I need to change so I can copy a value from one workbook and paste it to the new workbook?

```
    # Import modules
    import xlwings as xw
    import os

    # Creates list of all excels in the directory 
    excel_list = os.listdir(r"C:\Desktop\excel_folder")

    # Opens a new blank workbook
    wb = xw.Book()

    # Count varible to adjust cell location
    cell_count = 1

    # Iterates through excel workbooks in the directroy 
    for excel in excel_list:
        # Opens an excel from the directory
        wb2 = xw.Book(r'C:\Desktop\excel_folder\{0}'.format(excel))
        # Grabs the needed value
        copy_value = xw.Range('D2',wkb=wb2).value
        # Addes the copy_value to the specified cell
        xw.Range('A{0}'.format(cell_count),wkb=wb).value = copy_values
        #Adjust the cell count
        cell_count +=1
        #Closes workbook
        wb2.close()

    print "Script complete"
```

Comment: I'll do that but that doesn't solve the problem that none of the values are getting copied to the new workbook.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to refer to a specific sheet in the workbook to write into. As per the comment below, `xw.Range('A1',wkb=wb).value` is deprecated.

```
import xlwings as xw
import os

# Creates list of all excels in the directory 
excel_list = os.listdir(r"Z:\sandbox\sheets")

# Opens a new blank workbook and get Sheet1
wb = xw.Book()
sht = wb.sheets['Sheet1'] 

# Count varible to adjust cell location
cell_count = 1

# Iterates through excel workbooks in the directroy 
for excel in excel_list:
    # Opens an excel from the directory
    wb2 = xw.Book(r'Z:\sandbox\sheets\{0}'.format(excel))
    # Grabs the needed value
    copy_value = wb2.sheets.active.range('B3')
    # Addes the copy_value to the specified cell
    sht.range('A{0}'.format(cell_count)).value = copy_value
    #Adjust the cell count
    cell_count +=1
    #Closes workbook
    wb2.close()

print("Script complete")
```

Comment: Note that `xw.Range('B3',wkb=wb2).value` is deprecated. Use `wb2.sheets.active.range('B3')` instead (or a specific sheet instead of the active one)

Comment: @FelixZumstein: Thanks I edited the answer to reflect this.

Comment: How can you do this copy and paste from a `range` of cells rather than just `B3`? How about `A1:B17`?